# GraphDB error Statement (3742, 6, 4301, 3657) found in one collection, but not found in another

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, graphdb, linked-data

Can anyone please explain why I keep getting this error when I make PUT requests to a GraphDB repository?

```
    ... 77 common frames omitted
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.server.repository.statements.StatementsController.getAddDataResult(StatementsController.java:400)
    at com.ontotext.trree.monitorRepository.MonitorRepositoryConnection.commit(MonitorRepositoryConnection.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepositoryConnection.commit(SailRepositoryConnection.java:160)
Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryException: org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.SailException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Statement (3742, 6, 4301, 3657) found in one collection, but not found in another!
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the repository is corrupted. You may try the `StorageTool` (https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/storage-tool.html) to analyase and try fixing it ...

Comment: Experienced such errors in conjunction with the use of RDF Rank indexes: in my case the issue was solved after upgrading to GDB 9.5.

Comment: Thanks @A'B, I am running GraphDB 9.0. I will try upgrading.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov the StorageTool didn't help at all.

Comment: @EdmondChuc have you resolved the issue? Can you please share what are the findings? Many thanks.

Comment: @verodigiorgio I have not resolved the issue. I am still on version 9.0 and this error happens sporadically every now and then.

Comment: @EdmondChuc thanks for your response. Unfortunately I had to reconstruct the whole repository. The support realised that this seems to be due to a copy while the repo is actively used, even though I didn't had any chance to understand when it happened. That's really unfortunate.